# distribute the elements of second array inside the first array randomly

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an array like this:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

And we want to randomly distribute the elements of another array in the above array:

```
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

So that for instance we have the result like this:

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 2, 3, 4, 'c', 5, 6 'd', 'e', 7, 8]
```

Note that the order of both arrays remain intact but the second array distributed randomly inside the first array.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please explain us the logic of the order you want in your new array. it's will help us understand your question

Comment: How about you generate a random number that varies from `0` to the `length-1` of the first array (so here 0 to 6), and insert the elements of the second array using a for loop into the randomly generated position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all indices of the given array, like here `0` for `a` and `1` for `b`, shuffle the array and take the values in order.

Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/1447675.

```js
const
    random = (...args) => {
        let array = args.reduce((r, [...a], i) => [...r, ...a.fill(i)], []),
            currentIndex = array.length,
            temporaryValue,
            randomIndex,
            indices = args.map(_ => 0);

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array.map(i => args[i][indices[i]++]);
    }
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    result = random(a, b);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Amazing Job... Thank you very much.... I tried not to pick up your solution this time but it works like nothing else :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could loop through array "b", use the .length of array "a" (which gets updated each splice) and splice values of "b" into "a" at random index of "a".

```js
const shuffle = (function() {

    const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    const b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

    // Initial "starting" index.
    const initialRndInt = getRandomInt(0, a.length);
    
    b.forEach((value, index) => {

        // Int used in the actual splicing.
        const followingRndInt = function() {

            // Just return initial int.
            if(index === 0) {

                return initialRndInt;
            }

            // kinda bad way to look where the previous value was placed, maybe just add extra variable to keep track of the index.
            return getRandomInt(a.indexOf(b[index - 1]) + 1, a.length);
        }();

        // Shove it in there.
        a.splice(followingRndInt, 0, value);
    });

    // Function from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
    }

    console.log(a);
})();
```